# Type hinting a JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, types, mypy, python-typing

I'd like to type-hint JSON objects with an unknown or changing structure (pulled in from external API). I'd like to avoid using `Any` or solutions like `cast()` as much as possible.

I believe the right hint is:

```
Json: TypeAlias = dict[str, "Json"] | list["Json"] | str | int | float | bool | None
```

#### Problem

I find this hint often doesn't work. The following code sample recreates the problem.

```py
import requests
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias

Json: TypeAlias = dict[str, "Json"] | list["Json"] | str | int | float | bool | None

res: requests.models.Response = requests.get(
    "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&nat=gb"
)

data: Json = res.json()

results: Json = data["results"]
```

On `data["results:]` I get the following complaints from mypy:

> No overload variant of "**getitem**" of "list" matches argument type "str"  [call-overload]

> Possible overload variants:
> def **getitem**(self, SupportsIndex, /) -> Json
> def **getitem**(self, slice, /) -> list[Json]

> Value of type "dict[str, Json] | list[Json] | str | int | float | bool | None" is not indexable  [index]

#### Question

What am I doing wrong? I've managed to find [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182#issuecomment-1320974824) which may well contain the solution, but if so, I'm not yet good enough with types to see it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a specific endpoint? Or are you trying to be general? If you need generality, then the best you can get is `str` for unparsed JSON or `dict` if you parsed it.

Comment: General. I do not have control over the endpoint or confidence that it will always return the expected structure. Otherwise I'd use dataclasses or Pydantic, which allows for much more confident typing.

Comment: This is a prime example for the rare situations, when using `typing.Any` is completely justified. Python's type system is just not strong enough to properly express a JSON-like data structure. Even the good people at `typeshed` use `Any` as the return type for [`json.load`/`json.loads`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f2ee9e9368a18b19bbf2ac05b6eb6bfea96d9a0c/stdlib/json/__init__.pyi#L39-L60) to this day. And they basically maintain the official type stubs for the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `str` is a valid instance of `Json`. So when you index a `Json` object, as in `data["results"]`, `mypy` complains that that is not a valid operation on a string. You probably want `data: dict[str, Json] = res.json()`. Or even better, a `TypedDict` specifying the entire structure of the document.

Comment: OP: I don't recommend going down the road of trying to type-hint JSON. This answer will address the immediate problem, but you'll encounter the same issue at every level of the structure. The underlying problem is that JSON can represent multiple types which have incompatible interfaces. Worse, the containers are allowed to be heterogeneous. If I write `my_json['key'][1]['value']`, I can't know *a priori* that `my_json` is a dict, `my_json['key']` is a list, and `my_json['key'][1]` is a dict, or what the overall result is. That requires *examining the JSON*, which happens at runtime.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If `my_json` comes from a specific endpoint who's return value is known, then you have all the *a priori* knowledge you need for the type hinting.

Comment: Theoretically, yes; but then we're talking about a "type hint" that encodes the entire JSON schema. Even then, I'm not sure that heterogeneous containers can be supported; what is the type hint for `{"foo": [1, 2], "bar": {"baz": "quux"}}` that ensures that `my_json['foo'][0]` and `my_json['bar']['baz']` are accepted? Indexing `my_json` gives a result that has different capabilities depending on what the string was. That seems like it at least requires `typing.cast` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks to all for helpful answers. @KarlKnechtel your warning makes sense. Given the context that I'm in strict mode and `Any` is discouraged, how would you approach (or not) type hinting here?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "strict mode". I also don't know what problem you are trying to solve by adding type hints. I personally do not use them, in large part because I keep running into questions like this one on Stack Overflow where there is some really complex type description needed with a vanishingly small chance of actually detecting an error.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you describe a `TypedDict` type - like [this one](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=e0515ad584ffacd1fecd29b0e5f9a571). Though I agree it makes very little sense in most cases (real use case I did - type hint a complex JSON output of a reusable library), benefit for a throwaway response is too low compared to work needed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel While I completely agree that in this instance, i.e. trying to annotate JSON, the type system is not nearly strong enough and OP should just _not_ do it, I am baffled by your reasoning for not using type hints _in general_. That is like saying _"I don't have a car because it is really hard to cross the Atlantic ocean in it."_ In 99.9% of situations type hints in Python are straightforward and _extremely_ useful. Not using them at all because of messed-up edge cases seems very misguided.

Comment: I offer them as documentation on my public API, basically. I agree they are normally straightforward. I disagree that they are useful, because then I'd also have to choose, setup and put up with an IDE when my text editor already works great and doesn't interrupt me with automatically typed text and suggestions. But everyone has their own workflow - and this is not a discussion forum, and I don't have any more to say about it.